# ¿Cómo actualizar un objecto en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, jtable, ordenamiento, colecciones

Estoy realizando un registro de medicamentos, donde a medida que se va agregando al jTable lo ingresado, tambien se crea un objeto prod y se agrega a un ArrayList para luego poder manipular ese ArrayList, por ejemplo aplicandole un ordenamiento QuickSort y luego mostrar los datos en el jTable con su nuevo orden.

El dilema está en que el administrador puede actualizar los atributos de algun medicamento (nombre,descripcion,precio de compra, precio de venta y cantidad), entonces al actualizar los datos del jTable tambien se deben actualizar los atributos de ese objeto en el ArrayList para que siempre esté con los datos correctos.

Sin embargo, no me reconoce esa "actualizacion" del objeto ya que cuando le doy en Mostrar (boton que ordena) no me tiene en cuenta el producto actualizado, sino que me muestra el original (el producto antes de actualizarlo)

```
private void btnActualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    if (val == true) { // condicional para verificar que la tabla no este vacia
        int op;
        do {
            codigo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el codigo del producto a actualizar: "));
            for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
                if (jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(codigo)) { // se busca si el codigo buscado esta en la tabla
                    nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nuevo nombre: ");
                    descrip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nueva descripcion: ");
                    pCompra = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nuevo precio de compra: "));
                    pVenta = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nuevo precio de venta: "));
                    cantidad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nueva cantidad del producto: "));

                    prod = new Producto(listaProductos.get(i).getCodigo(), nombre, descrip, pCompra, pVenta, cantidad);
                    listaProductos.add(i, prod); // se agrega en la posicion del codigo encontrado, el nuevo objeto con sus parametros

                    // se muestran los nuevos valores en el jTable
                    jTable1.setValueAt(nombre, i, 1);
                    jTable1.setValueAt(descrip, i, 2);
                    jTable1.setValueAt(pCompra, i, 3);
                    jTable1.setValueAt(pVenta, i, 4);
                    jTable1.setValueAt(cantidad, i, 5);
                    break;
                }
            }
            op = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea actualizar otro producto?");
        } while (op == 0);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "REGISTRO VACÍO", "IMPORTANTE", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Ahora, este es el boton de Mostrar

```
private void btnMostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (val == true) {
        QuickSort(listaProductos, 0, listaProductos.size()-1);

        for(int i = 0;i < listaProductos.size()-1;i++){
            // Se muestran los nuevos valores ya ordenados
            modelo.setValueAt(listaProductos.get(i).getCodigo(), i, 0);
            modelo.setValueAt(listaProductos.get(i).getNombre(), i, 1);
            modelo.setValueAt(listaProductos.get(i).getDescripcion(), i, 2);
            modelo.setValueAt(listaProductos.get(i).getPrecioCompra(), i, 3);
            modelo.setValueAt(listaProductos.get(i).getPrecioVenta(), i, 4);
            modelo.setValueAt(listaProductos.get(i).getCantidad(), i, 5);
        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "REGISTRO VACÍO", "IMPORTANTE", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Datos ingresados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dato actualizado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos que muestra ordenados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El parametro de referencia por el cual se ordena es el precio de venta y se quiere ordenar de menor a mayor, como vemos no me tiene en cuenta el producto actualizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba usando el metodo .add y el que tengo que usar es el .set para "sobreescribir" el objeto anterior con el nuevo.

```
prod = new Producto(listaProductos.get(i).getCodigo(), nombre, descrip, pCompra, pVenta, cantidad);
listaProductos.set(i, prod); // se agrega en la posicion del codigo encontrado, el nuevo objeto con sus parametros
```